# VSTO Licensing thru Office Store or Private

Tags: outlook, vsto, developer-tools

I have created an Outlook addin, and I want to license it/sell it.

I would like to think that Microsoft would have a solution or SDK for this somewhere, but I can't find anything like that.

Does anyone have any sample code on how to do that with the Microsoft Store, or do I have to create one from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not allow VSTO or any other COM addins in its store. There is a store for the web based addins only.

Comment: So, if I want to license it, I have to write the system manually?

Comment: That is correct - you will need to host the download and handle licensing on your own.